# How to get wiki template's content?

Tags: api, templates, mediawiki

Does anybody know how to get access to the template's body inside the page?

I'm familiar with the API that returns the list of ALL templates that exist [on the page](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=templates&titles=Main%20Page), but how I can get access to the template's body? Is there any API for this? For now I see only one possible way... parse it manually. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [expandtemplates](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Expandtemplates) API call, or the `rvexpandtemplates` parameter for the [revisions](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Query_-_Properties#revisions_.2F_rv) API call.

Comment: and how I can get content of "Template:Infobox writer" on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Shakespeare page for example?

Comment: The expandtemplates api, when called with `generatexml=1`, transforms wikitext to an XML tree where every template argument is a separate leaf.

Comment: Thanks, this is extremely helpful, as it would have been very hard to discover through the API docs.  Also note that the two methods mentioned are quite different: `expandtemplates` gives you the rendered (X)HTML as you'd see it on the wiki page, whereas the `revisions` approach gives essentially a direct parse of the template.  In both cases, the output is escaped according to the requested `format`.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but it helped me figure out how to fetch a mediawiki page with template macros expanded.  Very useful if you are doing a conversion.

```
<MW_BASEURL>/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions
   &titles=<url_encoded_page_title>&format=xml&rvprop=content&rvexpandtemplates
```

I am parsing the xml returned from this query to get the expanded page.

Comment: Thanks very much! The current implementation of mediawiki does not take care of templates well. I hope they can fix it in the next version.